# How to correlate between FM CV input on VCO and the FM Modulation Index?

Tags: modulation, synthesis

The frequency modulation theory revolves around Carrier Frequency (**fc**), Modulating Frequency (**fm**) and the Modulation index (**β**). The position and amplitude of sidebands depends on these factors. But when I see any VCO, it just has **FM CV/ FM Depth** input in percentage. I didn't understand how this control correlates with the factors fm, fc and β. Can anyone please help me in understanding this?

I have tried to understand this and here are some of my findings:
As the control "FM CV" is in percentage, I thought it might be related to percentage Frequency Modulation concept. According to this,
**%FM = (β * fm)/Δfc**
where Δfc is maximum carrier frequency deviation after it is modulated.
In the above formula, I have fm, β (which I can assume based on whether I want Narrow band FM or Wide band FM). But I didn't understand how to get Δfc value i.e., the maximum carrier frequency deviation. I got stuck here. Please share your thoughts on these findings too.

Comment: Apart from the fact I understand almost nothing of what you said… are you confusing FM synthesis with regular subtractive synthesis?

Comment: Could you point a specific module/synth that shows the kind of parameters? If it is a vco, there is also a CV for it's frequency for instance.

Comment: @Tetsujin , I'm trying to understand the correlation between the FM theory and its practical application in FM Synthesis. Can you please be clear on what exactly you didn't understand. In case you didn't understand the terminology like carrier frequency, modulation index etc., please refer the following article: https://www.soundonsound.com/techniques/introduction-frequency-modulation

Comment: @Tom , I'm using VCV rack for Synthesis. In that I'm using VCO-1 module as my oscillator.  Please refer this manual for the details of that VCO: https://vcvrack.com/Fundamental#manual . In this VCO, there is an FM input where the modulating frequency signal is connected and FM CV knob to control that. I'm trying to understand the correlation between that FM CV and the theoritical parameters of Frequency Modulation as I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: @RAMMOHANMODUPALLI This simulates a 1V/octave exponential FM arrangement according to the manual.  See my answer below for more explanation.

Comment: @RAMMOHANMODUPALLI If you aren't getting the answers you hope for here, consider asking at [math.se] or [engineering.se].

Answer (score 1):

The best answer will come from the manufacturer of the VCO.  They have the latitude to decide what is musically useful, and what they wish to accommodate in the electronics design.

There are two basic kinds of modulation:

- Linear (e.g. 100 Hertz/Volt)
- Exponential (e.g. 1V/octave)

For exponential FM, 1V/octave is common, since it is the most common standard used for the pitch (carrier) input.  This means that for each volt of modulation input, the frequency doubles.

The percentage control will just scale (attenuate) the control voltage input (of either kind).

This page explains the differences between the two pretty well:  [Understanding the Differences Between Exponential, Linear, and Through Zero FM](https://learningmodular.com/understanding-the-differences-between-exponential-linear-and-through-zero-fm/) (Through-zero is a feature that allows linear FM to modulate below 0 Hz gracefully.  It's not a problem on logarithmic FM because the carrier can only be modulated asymptotically toward zero.)

Although sidebands are of course created by the modulation just as they would be at radio frequencies, I think it's unusual in a music-synthesis setting to be concerned with their exact frequency and amplitude.  The distinction between narrow- and wide-band may not be useful in this setting.  Probably, most FM synthesis would be considered wide-band, but consider that the modulation depth itself could be modulated by envelope or LFO, so that it might classify as narrow-band at some points in time.

More often, these parameters are adjusted through educated trial-and-error guided by the sound that's being produced.  I'm curious about your application and how you might be planning on using it.

Thank you for asking this question!  I am a professional electrical engineer with music as a sideline.  I have not worked first hand with modern modular synthesizers and didn't know previously how these features are commonly implemented, so it gave me an excuse to read a bit about it.

Comment: Thanks for your time in answering this. I, being a beginner in Music Synthesis, am trying to make my fundamentals clear in terms of theory and correlating it with the practice. The Exponential FM. Linear FM etc., are related to how the Input FM CV should behave. But I'm interested in how that FM CV is controlling the Spectrum. For  example, If I know β , fm I can clearly say that the Band width or range of frequencies is 2(β+1)fm. But I don't know on what factors this FM CV does Frequency Modulation. I'm trying to understand that.